# Citas textuales en formato IEEE

Tags: citas, lenguaje-académico

Estoy elaborando un trabajo en el cual se tiene que realizar citas usando el formato IEEE, pero por lo general veo que los textos con este formato no usan comillas para citar. Sin embargo, mi citación es de varios renglones, ¿cómo se citaría en ese caso?

Yo pensaría que es algo así:

> Tomando otro perfil profesional que describe a los ingenieros de sistemas, encontramos que es un profesional “...con sólida formación científica, con conocimientos propios de las áreas de ingeniería de software, inteligencia artificial, telecomunicaciones, investigación de operaciones y bases de datos...MAS TEXTO..."[1]

¿Estaría correcto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se ve bien.  Agrega el número de página y utiliza una letra mas pequeña para la cita.

http://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/ieeereferencing/gettingstarted

An example of a longer direct quote:

If you use longer quotations (of three lines and more), use a block quotation by setting the block of quoted text as a paragraph. Use smaller font size for block quotations, and also indent them from both margins, for example:

As Abad notes:

> It is also desirable to minimize the parasitic capacitance of
>   electronic packages because it is another source of signal delay.
>   Consequently, a very low relative dielectric constant insulating
>   material should be used whenever possible, since the relative
>   dielectric constant is a measure of a material's total polarizability
>   and determines its charge storage capacity with respect to a vacuum
>   [7, p. 63].

Provide the in-text citation in square brackets after the quotation, along with the page number(s) of the source where the quoted words or phrases are taken from.

[image: screenshot of example]